# Windows Azure and web.config settings

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-config

I'm new to Windows Azure and just created my first "Web Site". Very easy and running well. 1 question though...

Does Azure ignore and/or override some or all settings that I have configured in my web.config file?

As a simple example, I have the following in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

But I still see many possible default documents listed on the Configure tab for my site.

It got me wondering what other settings it is ignoring.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `<clear/>` line, I would not expect any of the default docs that you see in the Azure portal to actually be effective. What the Azure portal shows is what ends up going in ApplicationHost.config, which your web.config overrides.

Are you saying that you still see the Azure portal values being effective at runtime? That would be puzzling.

Comment: Nope, that sounds like a good explanation. If Azure settings go in ApplicationHost.config and are overridden by web.config, then I'm not concerned. I'm just saying, I think the control panel would be more clear if that was explained somewhere. Better yet would be if it could read the web.config file and grey out options that will be overridden.

Comment: Agreed this could be clearer. BTW, you can look at the generated ApplicationHost.config to see this in action. You can do this using Kudu Console (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console), and going to ..\config from the starting location.

Answer (score 0):

IIS in Windows lists several common default documents when you manage a site(home.html, index.php, etc).  What you have listed in your web.config is not the list of possible default documents, it is the exact default document for your application.  Azure is showing you common default documents in the configuration manager and will override your web.config if you choose something different.

Comment: Yes, that is why I have the line `<clear />` in there. Try it with IIS on a physical server and you will see that it only shows the values you add after that. Azure isn't behaving the same way.